# Accessing a wallet from multiple devices

Tags: wallet, electrum, mobile

I'm using an Electrum wallet on my laptop. I'd like to have the functionality available on my phone (i.e. send/receive bitcoins - to the same wallet).

Is there a way to install one of the myriad of Android wallets, and "import" my wallet into them? Is that even the right approach? If not, what's the best way to use wallets on multiple devices?

Comment: you need the wallet file, on a pc the path is `C:\Users\<USER NAME>\AppData\Roaming\Electrum\wallets`, and the private keys for this file

Comment: Did I need to copy the file to the phone? Or have it accessible from both platforms?

Comment: not sure about phones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Android version of Electrum. Just enter the seed words.

Comment: And will it import my wallet, will all the transactions, and allow me to send/receive?

Comment: Yes, it will...

Comment: just installed. It asks me to create a new wallet. Then I have to type in the seed, letter by letter, on a virtual keyboard. Who came up with this? :)
Any alternatives?

Comment: You should also be able to choose `I already have a seed`. I assume the virtual keyboard is some kind of extra security in case you're using a special Android-keyboard (like swiping or what not) that might be potentially unsafe.

Comment: That makes sense. One final question: will adding the seed on the phone do anything to the wallet on the computer, or will they both be usable?

Comment: They will both be usable...